# Elasticsearch - finding values of a field based on the absence of a value on the other field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a **Elasticsearch** *index* with documents as follow:

```
{
"field1": "a1",
"field2": "b1"
}
-----------
{
"field1": "a1",
"field2": "b2"
}
-----------
{
"field1": "a2",
"field2": "b2"
}
-----------
```

Now, I want to find all such values of field1, for whom there exists no any document in the entire index, where value of field2 is b2.
So, looking just at above 3 documents, a2 and a1 should not be returned because they each have a record where field2 is b2.

Is it possible to create a query to achieve this in Elasticsearch ?

Comment: Can you explain why `a2` should not be returned?

Comment: a2 should not be returned because it already has a document/record where corresponding field2 has value b2. So, a2 will only be returned if all the records having field1 = a2, don't have a corresponding field2 = b2

Comment: Are you saying that `select data from index where field1=a2 and field2!=b2`. But what is that all the records?

Comment: @oblivion Do you want a1 to be returned in this scenario. Won't that apply like a2 as well as there is a document with a1 having b2 as well. In this scenario none of them should return correct.

Comment: Yes you are right. Both a1 and a2 cannot be returned. Sorry, my mistake. I edited the question now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that is not possible unless you change your mapping.

If you get to change your mapping, it could be as done with as easy as writing a simple [Bool must_not](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query and you would get what you have.

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_test_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field1": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "field2": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "possible_values_field2":{             <----- Notice this field
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST my_test_index/_doc/1
{
  "field1": "a1",
  "field2": "b1",
  "possible_values_field2": [ 
    "b1", "b2"
    ]
}

POST my_test_index/_doc/2
{
  "field1": "a1",
  "field2": "b2",
  "possible_values_field2": [ 
    "b1", "b2"
    ]
}

POST my_test_index/_doc/3
{
  "field1": "a2",
  "field2": "b1",
  "possible_values_field2": [ 
    "b1", "b2"
    ]
}

POST my_test_index/_doc/4
{
  "field1": "a2",
  "field2": "b2",
  "possible_values_field2": [ 
    "b1", "b2"
    ]
}

POST my_test_index/_doc/5
{
  "field1": "a3",
  "field2": "b3",
  "possible_values_field2": [ 
    "b1", "b3"
    ]
}

POST my_test_index/_doc/6
{
  "field1": "a3",
  "field2": "b1",
  "possible_values_field2": [ 
    "b1", "b3"
    ]
}
```

### Request Query:

```
POST my_test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "possible_values_field2": {
              "value": "b2"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 814,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "field1" : "a3",
          "field2" : "b3",
          "possible_values_field2" : [
            "b1",
            "b3"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_test_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "field1" : "a3",
          "field2" : "b1",
          "possible_values_field2" : [
            "b1",
            "b3"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Aggregation Solution:

You can also make use of [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on top of that query to get what you want.

Something like below:

```
POST my_test_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "possible_values_field2": {
              "value": "b2"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_field1_values": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response would look like:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_field1_values" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "a3",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Sorry, this does not help as I cant change the mapping of the index. But, I do appreciate the idea here. So, if we do know possible values of field2, can we build such query then ? (with the original mapping ofcourse)

Comment: What did I misunderstand? @Kamal

Comment: @oblivion I don't know if that is possible. I will think through again but I doubt if that is possible.

Comment: hey @Gibbs, so what user wants is basically to return all values of `field1`, which does not have field2 with value b2. So if you have two different docs, `doc1` having `field1: a, field2:b1` and `doc2` with `field1:a, field2:b2` you should not return either of them i.e. not even `doc1` coz there exists one document in the index with field2 set as b2 for that `field1:a`.

Did that help!!?? :(